# Stopping a Service from Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have problem with stopping a service from activity.

Declaration of my service:

```
public class MyService extends Service implements LocationListener { .. }
```

This service is called when the button is pressed:

```
public void startMyService(View view)
{
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), MyService.class.getName());
    ComponentName service = startService(new Intent().setComponent(comp));
}
```

In another method (launched by button click) I want to stop it:

```
public void stopMyService(View view)
{
    stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}
```

Unfortunately, it is not working. It seems to me that this service is replaced by another one. Furthermore, it´s cumulating - for example, when I start the service for the second time, there are two of them, running, etc. Could somebody help me? Thanks in advance for your help.

UPDATE : Android Manifest (only my service):

```
<service android:name=".MyService" 
        android:enabled="true" 
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="LocationTrackingService" 
        />
```

Comment: Don't use

this.service = startService(new Intent().setComponent(comp));

Comment: just write it as startService(new Intent().setComponent(comp)); only

Comment: Show your manifest file.

Comment: sorry `this.service` was typing mistake. I´ve updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a BroadcastReceiver to your service (or a static method - depending on your preferences) and call `Context.stopService()` or `stopSelf()`, e.g. add ...

```
public static String STOP_SERVICE = "com.company.SEND_STOP_SERVICE";

private final BroadcastReceiver stopReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      if(intent.getAction().equals(STOP_SERVICE)){
          MyService.this.stopSelf();
      }
   }
};
```

... to your service (assuming it's called `MyService`). Then call `registerReceiver(stopReceiver, STOP_SERVICE);` in the `onStartCommand()` method and `unregisterReceiver(stopReceiver);` in `onDestroy()`. Finally send the broadcast from anywhere you need to stop the service:

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setAction(MyService.STOP_SERVICE);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

If you have some threads you have to stop them before (probably you have and you started the service *sticky*, did you?)

Comment: I haven´t mention STICKY/NOT_STICKY in my code, so I think you´re right. If I start my service as NOT_STICKY, wouldn´t it solve the problem?

Comment: If you start your service as not sticky (I think that's the default) it might end right after execution. Starting sticky requires explicitly stopping the service. As long as it is not stopped you can't start it again. You could try to set it to NOT_STICKY - may be I'm wrong about the default and it works as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. But there is a problem - your solution is not applicable for my problem, the error occurs: `The method stopSelf() is undefined for the type new BroadcastReceiver(){}`

Comment: No I haven't tested it, but I'm pretty sure that it works that way - apart from small compiling issues. Sure, `this` would be the BroadcastReceiver; it should be `getApplicationContext().stopService(...)`. You could also store a reference to the service in the `onStartCommand()` method and use this for `stopSelf()`

Comment: I mean `action`, mentioned inside `BroadcastReceiver` - it just doesn´t work. (`action cannot be resolved`)

Comment: Not a big deal ... see change